# Making the circle dilate until clicked

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So I'm using corona and I'm trying to create a game that has a circle that gets bigger and smaller until its clicked in which it stops dilating and a new circle appears which then starts dilating as well. The point of the game is to fit as many circles inside one another as possible. My problem is I've been able to make an infinite loop so that the circle will get bigger and smaller forever but now I'm trying to make it so that when its clicked it stops. I've tried putting it in a loop and while the number of clicks is one it will go and then when its two it will stop but its not working. Can you guys help?

Here's the code that I have right now and nothing happens except for a little circle showing up.

```
circa = display.newCircle(display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight/2, 20)
circa:setFillColor(noFillColor)
circa.strokeWidth=5
circa:setStrokeColor(1,0,0)

local function numberOfCircles ( event )

  if (event.numTaps==1) then
    x=1
  elseif (event.numTaps==2) then 
    x=2
  end

end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame" , numberOfCircles)

while x==1 do

  i = i + 1

  local function startCircle(event)
    resize = circa.path
    circa.scale=transition.to( resize, {radius = 300, time=1000, x= event.x, y=event.y})
  end


  local function endCircle( event )
    reresize = circa.path
    circa.scale = transition.to( resize, {radius = 20, time=1000, x= event.x, y = event.y})
  end

  timer.performWithDelay(1000*i, startCircle)
  timer.performWithDelay(2000*i+1,endCircle)
end


if x == 2 then
  circa.setLinearVelocity(0, 0)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve that is to do 2 changes in your code.

First, let's get ride of your infinite loop. We can achieve the same effect by using the transition repeat mode.

Then, we just add a tag to your transition, so you can easily cancel your transition by calling transition.cancel("tagname").

Here is how your code would be:

```
circa = display.newCircle(display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight/2, 20)
circa:setFillColor(noFillColor)
circa.strokeWidth=5
circa:setStrokeColor(1,0,0)


local scaleFactor = 300/20

transition.to(circa, {xScale=scaleFactor, yScale=scaleFactor, time=1500, transition= easing.continuousLoop,iterations=-1, tag="myTransition"})


local function onBackgroundTap(e)

    print("user clicked on background. Let's stop transition")

    transition.cancel("myTransition")

end

Runtime:addEventListener("tap", onBackgroundTap)
```

Comment: Do you know how I would make an if statement that ends everything if the circle clicked is bigger than the previous circle?

Comment: hummm. Probably adding a "enterFrame" listener that stores the current circle size and saves the previous circle size  and then on the "tap" listener I would check those values (current circle size  x  previous circle size) and then cancel the transition (if the case)

Comment: I tried that but it wasn't working out, can you show me how to do it? Also, my score counter keeps printing on top of itself so it'd be great if you could tell me how to fix that too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do u mean by score counter? You have a label on screen showing the counter?